# ASPX Jquery 1.11 $(Document).ready(function() {} was skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm a freshman to Jquery, and I tried to load this when the html was opened, but `ready()` was not called.

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(Document).ready(function() {
            alert("HelloWorld");
            });
        })
    </script>
<title></title>
```

The `alert()` didn't pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. It is "document",  not "Document". Case matters.
2. You have an extra "})" at the end of your script.

Your code works after those two corrections:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("HelloWorld");
    });
</script>
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/2tvv6tLc/

Answer (score -1):

You should have a lowercase 'd' in document:

`$(document).ready(function() {
     alert("HelloWorld");
 });`

Answer (score -1):

Learn to read [the documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and check your client side for errors (usually F12 in your browser and check the Console tab). It will save you from asking a question that can be answered in under a minute.

The correct way is

```
$(document).ready(function() { alert("HelloWorld"); });
```

Notice the lower case "d"? And the number of curly braces and parentheses are balanced.

The shorthand equivalent for this is...

```
$(function() { alert("HelloWorld"); });
```